# What paper and ink types are better suited for hot weather conditions?

Tags: print-design, paper, ink

I am a Realtor in the Phoenix metropolitan area and do all of my own art work in InDesign.  Currently, I am printing flyers for my listings.  These flyers are placed in an outside box for drive by clients to pick up and read about the home.

I am printing these flyers on Hammermill Color Laser Gloss 32 lbs Brightness 94 paper with a Canon BizHub office laser printer. What I am finding is that after a day in hot Phoenix sun, many of these flyers stick together and are damaged.

I went to Kelly paper and tried a heavier semigloss and non-gloss papers. But they, too, will stick together.

What paper and ink should I use so I can avoid the flyers sticking together, even in hot and sunny conditions?

Comment: Do they stick together before or after printing? If it's only after being printed then it's probably the ink rather than the paper that's getting sticky. If the unprinted paper sticks together then you might need to consider using something uncoated.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. There a couple of things that you might want to consider after knowing that:

1. Laser ink is a dye-sublimation ink. In short, this means that this process is about using heat to transfer the pigment to the paper. It's just not ink sitting ON the paper, but imbeds into the fibers of the paper. So, when sitting out in the hot sun, the heat is activating the ink once again creating a hot mess. Ugh.

Read more on dye sublimation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dye-sublimation_printer

2. Second, the gloss paper has its own coating, thus, creating a secondary mess in hot weather.

You might consider:

- Moving the box to shade
- Digitally printing on uncoated paper, or
- Having a plastic sign printed with the same flyer design that's large
  enough to have buyers take photos of, or
- On your realtor sign, include a tiny url (http://tinyurl.com/) of the direct link to the specs on your Web site.

HTH!

Lisa

Comment: Good idea with the sign/short url - i have seen both used, also seen are QR codes to redirect online queries.

Comment: Mark, I <3 the idea of a QR code. I use them whenever possible and unfortunately, I've run into many folks in the US who feel the QR code is dead and passe. This is the only reason why I didn't include it as an option -I don't want Don to hit the same brick wall.

Comment: Yeah i tend to agree about the QR code thing in direct advertising but they do have a functional purpose, as does a barcode in a stock inventory/checkout shop situation.

Answer (score 1):

The weather here in Sydney is often hot and humid and also has a detrimental effect on particular coated stocks. We should try and keep paper stock, dark, cool and dry, consistently - if possible once the supplier wrapper has been removed, in an air tight box.

One of the methods you might be able to use is Silica Gel Desiccant - you can buy these online. Just drop a couple of these little packets in and this can help to reduce moisture buildup. Maybe try using a different kind of container or add rice in the bottom (to help absorb more moisture).